# Javascript Date.toDateString return value does not have splice

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't the following work?

```
var variable = new Date();
alert (variable.toDateString().splice(4));
```

Comment: Do you really want `splice`, or `slice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) does not have the method `splice`, you might want [String#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) instead. [Arrays however has splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).